# Do I need to allow bots on /* if I disallow /specific-directory?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

If I want all bots to **not** crawl `/specific-directory`, but I want them to operate "as usual" (thus: crawl) **all other directories** of my site, is this robots.txt entry adequate?

```
# All Bots
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

# SemRush
User-agent: SemrushBot
Disallow: /
```

Or, do I need to specifically allow `/allowed-directories` since I deny access to *some* directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disallowing specific directory is enough. There is no need to explicitly allow a directory unless it is a subdirectory of the disallowed one.

Your robots.txt looks fine.